# Symfony doctrine Cannot change column 'id'

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on AngularJS App with Symfony 2.7 and i have a register form that does not work, I'm unable to register a new user in the database. 
The first error occurred

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
```

Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform
   may not support it.

So i edited my config file by adding :

```
mapping_types:
        enum: string
```

and i executed :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I received this error message :

```
    [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
```

An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE user CHANGE id id INT AU
  TO_INCREMENT NOT NULL ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions to resolve your problems from documentation : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/mysql-enums.html .

**First one and easier:**

You can map ENUMs to varchars. You can register MySQL ENUMs to map to Doctrine varchars. This way Doctrine always resolves ENUMs to Doctrine varchars. It will even detect this match correctly when using SchemaTool update commands.

```
<?php
$conn = $em->getConnection();
$conn->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

In this case you have to ensure that each varchar field that is an enum in the database only gets passed the allowed values. You can easily enforce this in your entities:

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class Article
{
    const STATUS_VISIBLE = 'visible';
    const STATUS_INVISIBLE = 'invisible';

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $status;

    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        if (!in_array($status, array(self::STATUS_VISIBLE, self::STATUS_INVISIBLE))) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid status");
        }
        $this->status = $status;
    }
}
```

If you want to actively create enums through the Doctrine Schema-Tool by using the columnDefinition attribute.

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class Article
{
    /** @Column(type="string", columnDefinition="ENUM('visible', 'invisible')") */
    private $status;
}
```